# React Router triggering a route with history

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing

I am trying to do a very basic routing process where I have a home page, and on this home page when clicking on a button I get redirected to the next page. I have 3 components - "**App, HomePage, and NextPage**". I am using a history object to push the new URL, and this part works.

However, I am not sure how to actually call the new route (e.g. make the App component render the new route. My code is as follows:

```js
    export default function App() {

      return (
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Switch>
             <Route path="/">
               <HomePage/>
             </Route>
              <Route path="/nextpage">
                <NextPage/>
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    }

    function HomePage () {
      let history = useHistory();

      function handleClick() {
        history.push("/nextpage");
      }

      return (
        <div>this is the home page
          <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Display next page</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    export default withRouter(HomePage);


    function NextPage () {
      return (
        <div>You just arrived to the next page!</div>
      )
    }

    export default NextPage;
```

Any idea what step I am missing? I have read the documentation but I am not clear who exactly triggers the rendering on the NextPage component, since clicking the button only modifies the history object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Pushing a new url onto the history will load that page as you expect, forcing a re-render with React

Comment: Hi Mikkel, thanks for your fast answer. This is not happening unfortunately. I am console logging the history object and I can see it updating, however I don't get redirected to the next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see now! Your code is not rendering the nextpage because the condition for the HomePage is still true, try to add "exact" to your first route, like this:

```
<Route exact path="/">
           <HomePage/>
</Route>
```

That's because when you use Switch it will render when the first Route condition returns true and will stop there. Some reference: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Prompt
Happy coding! :D And welcome to Stack Overflow!!!